# Bouncycastle RSA key size and Padding

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

I am using the RSA implementation from Bouncycastle. I am getting a cipher instance with the following options,

```
"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"
```

My question is how do you pick which padding to use? and What is the max amount of data I can encrypt? AFAIK RSA has a limit. I also can not find what ECB stand for?

Comment: ECB = Electronic Codeebook https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29

Comment: The mode, ECB in this case, is ignored for RSA.Use PKCSPadding. The max amount of data you can encrypt is the size of the modulus in bytes minus 11.

Comment: @HamzaYerlikaya, could add more details in the question why do you use "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" and what are you trying to archive with this cipher.

Comment: @Vladimir I am going to use this to encrypt a AES key which in turn will encrypt a big file. "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" got this setting from a bouncycastle example so I wanna know what each option does.

Answer (score 0):

In the rsa the encrypt mode is ignored. if you have a large date to encrypt,  calculate the blocks number yourself and the belowing example may help you:

```
        byte[] var21;
        try {

            Cipher cp = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", new BouncyCastleProvider());
            cp.init(mode, key);
            int blockSize = cp.getBlockSize();
            int blocksNum = (int) Math.ceil((double) data.length / (double) blockSize);
            int calcSize = blockSize;
            Object buffer = null;
            outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            for (int i = 0; i < blocksNum; ++i) {
                if (i == blocksNum - 1) {
                    calcSize = data.length - i * blockSize;
                }

                byte[] var22 = cp.doFinal(data, i * blockSize, calcSize);

                try {
                    outputStream.write(var22);
                } catch (IOException var19) {
                    throw new GeneralSecurityException("RSA error", var19);
                }
            }
            var21 = outputStream.toByteArray();
        } finally {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException var18) {
                    ;
                }
            }

        }
```